# Is it possible to buy shares of some big company while working as a student in foreign university?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

I am working as a researcher in a University outside my own country. I want to know is it possible to buy shares or should I ask for permission from university or the government of that country (Its a European country BTW)? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, ask your broker, they should know what the requirements are.

Comment: What are possible concerns?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler For example in my country of origin it is not legal for a government worker to have another business. So I am not sure if this also applies here